# Index not found

Tags: php, content-management-system

I have these 2 PHP files, and I don't know why but I'm getting an error:

> SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
>   ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: content in D:\wamp\www\admin\add-script.php on line 11

This is the add-script.php

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
    $db = mysqli_select_db($con,$db) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

    if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $category = $_POST['category'];
        $tags = $_POST['tags'];
        $image = $_POST['image'];
        $content = $_POST['content'];
        $time = time();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO articles (article_id, article_title, article_content, article_timestamp, article_tags, article_image, article_category) VALUES ('', '$title','$content','$time','$tags','$image','$category')";

        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        {
            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }

        ('Location: index.php');
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
?>
```

and this is add.php

```
<?php
     session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
        include_once ("header.php");
        include_once ("add-script.php");
?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form method="post" id="add" name="add" >
                <div id="left-col">
                     <h1>Add Article</h1>
                     <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" />
                     <textarea name="content" rows="30" id="markItUp content" cols="106" placeholder="Content"> </textarea>
                     <input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Tags" />
                     <input type="text" name="image" placeholder="Image Name" />
                 </div>
                 <div id="right-col">
                     <?php 
                         $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category");
                         while($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                     ?>
                     <input type="radio" name = "category" value = "<?php echo $list['category_id']; ?>">
                     <label><?php echo $list['category_name']; ?></label>
                     <?php 
                         }
                     ?>
                     <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send!" style="margin-bottom:0px;"/>
                 </div>
             </form>
         </td>
<?php    
    include_once ("footer.php");
    }
    else {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Start by making sure your html is valid: `div  id="right-col">`

Comment: Sorry... now to the php stuff... why am i getting this error?

Comment: Your query is wide open to SQL injection. You should be using prepared statements.

Comment: What? sorry i don`t understand

Comment: is article_id your primary key for articles table ? & what is your article_timestamp Datatype ? is there any special reason why you include add-script.php rather than using form action ?

Comment: my primary key is article_id and article_timestamp is int with a length of 11.. i used this cause i`m always upgrading features of the site and it`s easier this way.. but i can change if necesary.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't use spaces as id values of elements like: `id="markItUp content"`
Change your id:s to lowercase letters without spaces like: `id="markitup_content"`.

Your error is telling that there is no value with index "content" in your post parameters:

```
$content = $_POST['content'];
```

Comment: I used id that way so that i can atribute 2 ids to that

Comment: and i don`t know why the hell it is happening

Comment: WTF.. you can't use two id:s in html.. why would you even ever need that? I give up if your knowledge is that level..

Comment: you can do that with classes, but not id's

Comment: Ok, but that is what the error is saying.. try change the name content to something else in your form and post reading code. You can also try to debug your post like `var_dump($_POST);`  and see if there is your params..

Comment: No change.. still the same error but with a diffrent name

Comment: SOLVED! i don`t know what have i done but it works now